# Passing javascript loop variable to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I pass variables in loop to a PHP file using AJAX?

```
var lat;
var lng;
var array = [ 22.399602, 114.041176, 22.344043, 114.0168, 22.327529, 114.087181 ];
console.log(array);
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 2) {
    lat = array[i];
    console.log("lat" + i + "=" + lat);
    for(var j = i + 1; j <= i + 1; j++) {
        lng = array[j];
        console.log("lng" + j + "=" + lng);
    }
}
```

My array is here:

[image]

In this case I want pass each `lat` and `long` to my database. My database will looks like this:

```
username: Neo
lat=22.399602
long=114.041176
lat=22.344043
long=114.0168
lat=22.327529
long=114.087181
```

I also test this AJAX function but it isn't working for an array.

```
$.post('send.php', { latitude: lat, longitude: lng }, function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
});
```

What should I do now?

Comment: `for(var j=i+1; j<=i+1;j++)` what's this for

Comment: How do you populate the array initially?

Comment: it's get lat, long from array. Array included both lat and long. 1st loop get lat, and second loop is get only longitude.

Comment: what error did `$.post()` give you?

Comment: i didn't use array send to php file using $.post() how to pass it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are certain that `array` will contain latitude and longitude one after the other then you don't need a nested loop.

```
var lat;
var lng;
var array = [22.399602,114.041176 , 22.344043,114.0168 , 22.327529,114.087181];
//console.log(array);
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i+=2)
{
    lat=array[i];
    long = array[i+1];
    console.log(lat+"    "+long);
    $.post('send.php', {latitude:lat, longitude:long}, 
    function(data)
    {
        $('#result').html(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to structure your initial array in a more logical manner the problem would be much simpler for you. Consider:

```
function sendlatlng(lat,lng){
    var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( http.readyState==4 && http.status==200 ) console.info( http.response );
    };
    var headers={
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };
    http.open('POST', '/send.php', true );
    for( header in headers ) http.setRequestHeader( header, headers[ header ] );
    http.send( 'lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng );
}



var array = [ [22.399602, 114.041176], [22.344043, 114.0168], [22.327529, 114.087181] ];

for( i=0; i < array.length; i++ ){
    lat=array[ i ][ 0 ];
    lng=array[ i ][ 1 ]
    console.log( 'lat: %s lng: %s',lat,lng );
    sendlatlng.call( this, lat, lng );
}
```